# Swift Navigation Bar not change userInterfaceStyle on scoll

Tags: swift, xcode, darkmode, uiuserinterfacestyle

I have a problem when I try to change interface style (dark or light). If I set dark mode I get the navigation bar remains light when I scroll. If I set light mode the navigation bar becomes black. How can I solve this?
I use this code to change userInterfaceStyle:

```
window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself.
For everyone that has this problem the solution is:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance
```

put this code inside TabBarController